# True Image scheduling settings

Tags: windows-7, backup, acronis-trueimage

I want a backup to run once a week. I want the scheme to be incremental so that only changes made since the last incremental back up or full backup will be saved. I need help with the settings for deleting old files. So I would like to do a full backup every 6 weeks.

If a full backup is done then all the previous backups should be erased. How else would it work? The oldest backup would be the first full backup and if that gets deleted then the next 5 incremental backups would be useless, so might as well delete them all. Or does someone have a better idea?

My question is, unless someone knows of a better scheme, how do you have all backups deleted just before a full backup happens? What should I put for the settings? I don't really know what a backup chain is but I guess it's all the backups that take place between full backups.
[image: screen shot]

UPDATE: I ended up going with the version chain method which looks like it does roughly what I want to do. Though it backups once a week, this is too much for me and it would be great if someone new how to change it to every two weeks

[image: screen shot]